# How can I get breadcrumbs when searching for a file or folder in google drive api?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

The situation is as follows: I did a search on google drive, after the search, the found files or folders are displayed. And now, when I go to the found folder, I want to receive data about all other parent folders of this folder with names for navigation on the site. Can you please tell me how can I do this?

I did the search like this:

```
window.gapi.client.drive.files
  .list({
    q: `name contains '${state.searchFileNameValue}'`,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, size, createdTime, mimeType, webViewLink, parents, sharingUser, webContentLink)'
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can retrieve the ids of the closest parents of a file by setting `fields` to `files(parents)` for the method [Files:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?authuser=0) or simply `parents` for the method [Files:get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

However, this works only for one level - to retrieve the parents of the nesting level above you will need to implement iteration that retrieves the parents of the parents etc. until the response is empty (`{}`).

Unfortunately there is no way to obtain all parents this in a single request.